# How to check if the text file exists in the solution directory?

Tags: c#, text-files, exists

I am making an C#, Windows Form Application.

How can I check if text file exists in the solution directory?

I'm going to use this on another computer, so I can't write the exact location, and I thought if I check the text file exists at the solution directory, it can work.

Is there another way I can do this?

```
if (File.Exists(@System.AppContext.BaseDirectory\"TextFileName.txt")) 
{
Console.WriteLine("The file exists.");
}
```

It gives 2 errors.

> CS1056  C# Unexpected character '\'

and

> CS1003  C# Syntax error, ',' expected

Comment: What is @ doing in front of system

Comment: I think you meant to do this System.AppContext.BaseDirectory + "\TextFileName.txt". And to make it even better you could do Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "TextFileName.txt")

Comment: @It'satrap I just thought, when we normally write exactly directory, we use @. I'm new at coding, and I don't know why we are using @, but I put it there.

Comment: new to coding is a different thing, not knowing what you are doing and why is different. This way you will always remain new to coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Path.Combine` to create the path.

```
var path= Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "TextFileName.txt")
if (File.Exists(path)) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("The file exists.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Path.Combine()` is verbose and meant to use for combining path, but here is the solution with [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
var path = $"{System.AppContext.BaseDirectory}\\TextFileName.txt"
if (File.Exists(path)) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("The file exists.");
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with link. Short answer to your comment is : This format used to replace variable with its value. In your case variable is `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`. Try my solution you will learn something new. 

Answer (score 0):

You came close.  Just a little change to the path string:

```
if (File.Exists(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory + "\\TextFileName.txt")) 
{
Console.WriteLine("The file exists.");
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to learn, why did we use double \ before the TextFileName?

Comment: @Pemifo `\\\` : this is an escape sequence for *backslash*. To understand what is *Escape sequences* go through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=vs-2019